# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /somepath/index.php on line 115

Tags: php

I got a problem, I get an error with this code:

```
<td><?=$datas[$i]['devicename']?></td>
```

This is the error I get:

> Notice: Undefined offset:  1 in /somepath/index.php on line 115

Any one know the solution please help me.

Comment: <td><?=$datas[$i]['devicename']?></td>

Comment: Trying to access non-existent index, uh?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%23php+Undefined+offset

Comment: i am using this code for viewing the contents and the file xxx.phtml

Comment: Ha i am using non-existent index

Comment: Hi kingcrunch...i ll check this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a notice telling you, that

```
$datas[1]
```

is not set.

Use `isset()` to check if the value exists.

Comment: You should still be able to use php code? `if (isset($datas[$i]) && isset($datas[$i]['devicename'])) {
    echo $datas[$i]['devicename'];
}`

Answer (score 1):

`$datas` is an array with less than two elements, or an associative one. Make sure it contains the value you expect, for example with

```
var_export($datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined offset 1 probably means that the array $datas does not have a key = to 1, or another  way to put it, $datas[1] does not exist.

Since you are using $i this is probably in a for loop. You should post the rest of the code!

EDIT (your code):

```
$datas = $this->datas;
for($i = 1; $i<= count($datas);$i++){ 
?> 
<tr><td>
<?=$datas[$i]['devicename']?>
</td><td>
<?=$datas[$i]['unique_id']?>
</td></tr>
```

Please add this to your code (after `$datas = $this->datas;`) and show it to us.

```
var_dump($datas)
```

(although from the top of my head, you should probably start counting $i from 0, since array keys in PHP start from 0. Like this-> `for($i = 0; $i<= count($datas);$i++){`)

Comment: $datas = $this->datas;
     for($i = 1; $i<= count($datas);$i++){ ?>
    <tr>
   <td><?=$datas[$i]['devicename']?></td> 
   <td><?=$datas[$i]['unique_id']?></td>       </tr.

Comment: I would also suggest reducing overhead by counting `$datas` only once and not each time the loop advances: `<? $datas = $this->datas; $datas_count = count($datas); for($i = 1; $i<= $datas_count; $i++){ ?> `